# GA regex delimiting only one word between 2 whitespaces

Tags: regex, delimiter, cpu-word, derivative

I have to write a regex (the fist one in my life :D) and match the following words:

> iluminación/
>
> iluminar/
>
> iluminado/
>
> (+ other derivatives that my occur: "illumin" + "ending")

BUT NOT THESE:

> /mejor iluminación /iluminar con ello./
> iluminar,/

I have tried

`^ilumin[a-z]+\b`

and it works but can't excludes "con ello" and the ",".

So I have a left but not a right word delimiter. "$" at the end does not work either.

Have you any ideas about how to do that? The result should be tested [here](https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester/).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: did you try negative lookahead?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I tried this ^(?!.*^ilumin[a-z]+).*$ but now I can't delimit the word form the left side, so "mejor iluminación" can't be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `ó` to the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

To exclude "con ello" and the "," you could use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!`

```
^ilumin[a-zó]+\b(?! con ello|,)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7HVpSL/1)

If you want to use the anchor `$` to assert the end of the line, you don't need the negative lookahead as `[a-zó]+` does not match a space.

```
^ilumin[a-zó]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7YdLbI/1)

Comment: Thanks for the hint "ó"! I have tried it with another example ^estudi[a-z]+$ to match all derivatives (estudi + ending, like estudiar, estudio, estudiantil, etc.) and the only derivatives it does not match are those preceded by sth or followed by sth: "mejor estudio"  "estudiabamos con ello"  "estudando,"

Comment: @Elena I am not sure what should and should not be a match there. If you see this demo, is that not correct? https://regex101.com/r/tsblXk/1

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! Yes, it is almost perfect except the word "MEJOR" before the "estudi.." and the "CON ELLO" after the "estudi..". These are the things I do not want to show up in the results.

Comment: @Elena If supported, you could use a negative lookbehind. `(?<!mejor )\bilumin[a-zó]+\b(?! con ello|,)` See https://regex101.com/r/rYoqq7/1 and https://regex101.com/r/KeG4gc/1 What tool or language are you using?

Comment: I need a regex to exclude anything (not only "mejor") that may appear before the word "estudi..." and anything after estudi...(not only "con ello"). With the regex ^(?!.*^estudi[a-z]+).*$  I have managed to exclude anything that comes after a word starting with estudi, but cannot exclude anything that comes before it. And I have to test the result only here: https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester/

Comment: @Elena That pattern checks if for example `estudia` is not at the start of the string. You could also use anchors `^` and `$` to only match that pattern `^estudi[a-z]+$`

Comment: Thanks for trying so hard to help me, really! I first tried with ^estudi[a-z]+$, but the dollar cannot limit the word and exclude everything that comes AFTER it. Thus, if you check in the regex tester (see above): estudiar, estudio, estudiantil, estudiabamos con ello, it will also match "estudiabamos con ello" and will not exclude what comes after estudiabamos. :(

Comment: @Elena If you open this link https://regex101.com/r/KeG4gc/1 you see the current test data. On the left top you can see that there is an option to `Update regex` Can you add to the test data exactly what you want to match and what you don't want to match and share the updated link?

Comment: Hi again! I am sorry I don´t see the option Update regex. Here are the phrases once again: estudiar, estudiante, mejor estudio, estudiantil, estudiabamos con ello, estudiando.

Comment: Here are the words to be matched: estudiar, estudiante, estudio, estudiantil, estudiabamos, estudiando

Comment: @Elena this will match all the words `(?<!mejor )\bestudi[a-z]+\b(?! con ello) ` See https://regex101.com/r/pchSq2/1

Comment: Is there an option like this: (?<!ANY SIGN)\bestudi[a-z]+\b(?! ANY SIGN). Any sign, letter or number before \bestudi[a-z]+\b and any sign, letter or number after \bestudi[a-z]+\b should be excluded. ("mejor" and "con ello" are just an example of something before and after the derivative "estudi", but it could be any word, number or a punctuation mark. THANK YOU SO MUCH The fourt bird for your HELP!!!

Comment: @Elena Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/CLhkfL/1 The update regex option is at the left top (Or click the 3 horizontal lines to show the sidebar) if you want to edit the content.

Comment: Yes, I also thougth this must be the right regex, but according to my task it should only be checked here:https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester/. And when done, it matches all estudi-derivatives that are not followed or preceded by something. So for example in case of "estudiamos + sth", it does not match "estudiamos". In case of "sth + estudio", it does not much "estudio".